# Can you embed Flash content from within a Firefox addon

Tags: flash, firefox-addon

I would like to embed a Flash object from within a Firefox addon.

This can be done with images:

```js
imgTest = function(document){      
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];            
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = 'chrome://extname/content/image.jpg';      
  h.appendChild(img);
}
```

When the same is done with Flash the Flash object does not show:

```js
flashTest = function(document){      
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];            
  var ob = document.createElement("object");
  var embed = document.createElement("embed");
  embed.type = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
  embed.src = 'chrome://extname/content/flash.swf';
  ob.appendChild(embed);      
  h.appendChild(ob);
}
```

Looking in Firebug the object is appended but the embed is greyed out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `document` points to a web page loaded in the browser's content area (at least you *seem* to have an HTML document, not a XUL document). Then the problem appears to be that this web page is not allowed to access `chrome://extname/`. If you want contents of your extension to be accessible to web pages then you should specify the [`contentaccessible` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible) in your `chrome.manifest`, e.g.:

```
content extname chrome/path/ contentaccessible=yes
```

Side-node: it happens to work for images because images start loading synchronously as soon as you set the `src` property - so the originator of the request is your extension and the request is allowed. Flash objects only start loading asynchronously, after being inserted into the document. Here the originator of the request is the web page and it is disallowed from making it in this case.

Comment: thanks. yes, document = wrappedJSObject.document. I have already used contentaccessible=yes, I didn't mention it as the image does not show without it. In chrome.manifest I have "content extname content/ contentaccessible=yes". Flash and image can be accessed directly eg. chrome://extname/content/flash.swf. flash and image are in extroot/content. neither are greyed out now, only the image shows?

Comment: could anyone confirm this is actually possible